# Properties of Determinant Help

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm super stuck. I have a severe brain injury but I'm trying really hard to get my degree. Please be gentle! Question is attached.

I guess I'm kind of stuck between not knowing what the question is asking me to confirm and where to start. I know it involves a sort of reverse engineering to find out what row operations have been used. When I see the $ta$, $rb$ and $sa$ thrown in, I get lost. What do those even mean?

Can someone help?

*Confirm the following identity without evaluating the determinant directly:*

$$\begin{vmatrix}
 a_1&  b_1+ta_1& b_1+rb_1+sa_1\\ 
 a_2& b_2+ta_2& c_2+rb_2+sa_2\\ 
 a_3&  b_3+ta_3& c_3+rb_3+sa_3
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
 a_1&a_2  &a_3 \\ 
 b_1&b_2  &b_3 \\ 
 c_1&c_2  &c_3
\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have an "=" as an entry in the matrix.  Should the sa be in there at all?

Comment: May be you can take a photo of the question (if it is from some printed material) or give a link if it is online,,,

Comment: My best guess is that the question is asking about
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 + ta_1 & c_1 + rb_1\\
a_2 & b_2 + ta_2 & c_2 + rb_2\\
a_3 & b_3 + ta_3 & c_3 + rb_3
\end{vmatrix}
$$
could you confirm whether this is correct?

Comment: Regarding your approach so far, I recommend thinking in terms of *column-operations* rather than row-operations.

Comment: I have read your small Vita ; congratulations for your efforts (I have a handicapped child, and I know the needed energy, from you and your surrounding...). As Praphulla Koushik has suggested, take a photo of the page, place it into a file, click on the icon with 2 little mountains and insert the image by copy-sliding it . In your transcription, it is very difficult to understand anything...

Comment: @JeanMarie that is a nice message :) :) Hope others have same helping heart like you,,,,

Comment: My **guess** is that there are typos in your question. It probably intended to ask you to prove that the determinants on the two sides below are *always* equal, regardless of the values of $a_i, b_i, c_i, r, s$ and $t$:
$$
\left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1+ta_1 & c_1+rb_1\color{red}{-sa_1}\\
a_2 & b_2+ta_2 & c_2+rb_2\color{red}{-sa_2}\\
a_3 & b_3+ta_3 & c_3+rb_3\color{red}{-sa_3}
\end{matrix}\right|
=
\left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3
\end{matrix}\right|.\tag{1}
$$
(It's just a guess. Please check if this is really what the question meant.)...

Comment: ...Here $a_1$ is a number and $ta_1$ means $a_1$ multiplied by $t$. Similarly for other $ta_i, rb_i$ or $sa_i$.

To prove $(1)$, you may make use of the following property of determinant, namely, the value of a determinant remains unchanged if a scalar multiple of a column is added to another. Thus the problems boils down to showing that the matrix on the right can be obtained by performing a series of column operations on the matrix on the left.